# Is is possible to bind a value to a Vue element in a function later?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm building an autocomplete feature Basically, what I DON'T want is to bind the element like this:

```
v-model="input"
```

Binding on the element with the v-model or v-bind, gives my input element a blank value.

Instead, I'd like my element to be able to pick up an old value or a value from the database as seen in the code below. I'd only like to bind the element's value to my variable named "input" after the page has loaded with all this data from the DB. The code below works great, but I have to use document.getElementById to update my element with the new value.

```
<div id="spvs" class="uk-form-controls">
     <input v-on:input="input = $event.target.value" v-on:keyup="getCompanies" name="company" id="company" class="uk-input {{$errors->has('company') ? ' uk-form-danger' : ''}}" placeholder="company name" 
            value="{{ old('company') || $errors->has('company')
                ? old('company') 
                : $property->getCompanyName()
            }}">

    <div v-if="spvs.length > 0" class="tm-autocomplete-box">
        <ul class="uk-list uk-list-striped tm-autocomplete-list">
            <li v-for="(spv, key) in spvs" @click="complete(key)"><span uk-icon="plus-circle" class="uk-margin-right"></span> @{{ spv.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd bind the element value to my 'input' variable when the user clicks one of the autocomplete items. Which runs a function called 'complete'.

```
methods:{
        complete: function(key){
            this.input = this.spvs[key].name;
            document.getElementById('company').value = this.input;
            this.spvs = '';
        },
```

So this is the line that I would like to replace with the new binding:

```
document.getElementById('company').value = this.input;
```

Comment: `Binding on the element with the v-model or v-bind, gives my input element a blank value. ` I don't see your codes deal with blank value. and if you don't like blank, you can set up one default value you like.

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks, however a default value will not work. I need to detect my old(data) or my databased data, which is dynamic as it pulls from the database or from an old (failed) 'post' request. The code above works perfectly, however instead of 'document.getElementById) I'd like to bind the element at that moment only.

Comment: In this case good practice is to show a loading animation and to deactivate the input element during it.

Answer (score 1):

So you want your `input` to have a old value when the component loads and then you want to update the value.Still you can use `v-model` as below.

*When component loads the input will have the old value you want to set it, and also you can update the value:*

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="oldValue">
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    oldValue: 'value from Database'
  }
})
```

If you want another way there it is:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :value="oldValue" @input="changeValue">
  <hr>
  The value of input is: {{oldValue}}
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    oldValue: 'value from Database'
  },
  methods: {
    changeValue(newValue) {
      this.oldValue = newValue.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

[See in action the first example](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/99nmyw68/)

[See in action the second example](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/m84ap6no/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :)

Unfortunately I had something like you suggest. However, this won't work for me, I can't pass my old PHP data to JavaScript. I am using an external JavaScript file (because this code needs to run on both an 'add' and 'edit' page) so I'm trying to keep it as re-usable as possible.

Doing things my way, I can pick up the old value from the database. The moment I use 'v-model' my old data or databased data is lost. 

I'd prefer the binding to take place in my script, only once the user clicks a suggestion.